# Tensor product decomposition of $SU(2)$ duplet representations

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, quantum-spin, representation-theory

I have a rather trivial question. I am looking for the decomposition of $1/2\otimes 1/2\otimes 1/2$. It should give, $0,1/2$ and $3/2$. I thought one must get as the overall dimension of this space 8, but counting, I just get 7. Does one have 2 singlets?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Adding 3 electron spins](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29443/).

Comment: The question is similar, true but I am more interested in the formal mathematical expression of this problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From where did you get the idea that one can get a spin zero representation? The product of an even/odd number of Fermion representations always gives a Boson/Fermion representation.

In your particular case, repeated use of $$1/2 \otimes s = (s-1/2) \oplus (s+1/2)$$ gives $$1/2  \otimes 1/2 \otimes 1/2=(0\oplus 1) \otimes 1/2 
= (0 \otimes 1/2) \oplus (1 \otimes 1/2) =1/2 \oplus (1/2 \oplus 3/2).$$
Thus one gets two spin 1/2 and one spin 3/2 representations.

Answer (score 3):

With the caveat that I'm 30+ years rusty at this stuff: *Two* 1/2's and *one* 3/2 (and *no* singlet) does have dimension 8.  And *Mathematica's* Clebsch-Gordon routines affirm this decomposition.