# Wave functions for three identical fermions

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter

I would like to express the wave functions for three identical particles, each with orbital angular momentum $L=1$ and spin angular momentum $S=1/2$, in terms of single-particle wave functions.  In other words, I would like to obtain the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients for this problem.

The problem is discussed in Sakurai's Quantum Mechanics textbook around p. 375 and in [Greiner and Muller's "Quantum Mechanics: Symmetries, 2nd Edition"](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Quantum-Mechanics-Symmetries-D-A-Bromley/dp/3540580808/ref=dp_ob_title_bk) on p. 300.  I know I have to find the spin wave functions and the orbital angular momentum wave functions separately, and then combine them to get fully antisymmetric wave functions.  I have the spin wave functions (four symmetric, 2 mixed symmetric under exchange of particles 1 and 2, and 2 mixed antisymmetric under exchange of 1 and 2), but I haven't been able to get a small enough number of angular momentum wave functions to get just 20 fully-antisymmetric total wave functions.

In Sakurai's book, p 376, eq'n (6.5.20), we see that the 20 states can be decomposed into 2 states with total angular momentum $j=1/2$, 4*3=12 with $j=3/2$, and 6 with $j=5/2$.  Could anyone fill in *how* Sakurai got 6 for $j=5/2$, 12 for $j=3/2$, and 2 for $j=1/2$?

Most importantly, referring to my comments on Y Macdisi's answer below, could anyone answer the following question:  Is the orbital angular momentum state with single particle wave functions $\alpha=1$, $\beta=0$, and $\gamma=0$ related in some way to the wave function with $\alpha=-1$, $\beta=0$, and $\gamma=0$, or $\alpha=1$, $\beta=-1$, and $\gamma=-1$, and so on?  I would love it if I could just keep the first set of values for $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, but I see no good reason to do that.

If anyone happens to know where this problem is discussed more fully, I would appreciate a reference.  Or, if anyone knows how to do this, I would appreciate help in knowing what the $j=3/2$ and $j=5/2$ states could be in terms of single-particle orbital ang. momentum states and spin states.  I think I actually have the normalization factors already, I just need to know what the single-particle states are.

Comment: Just for the record, I don't have Sakurai in front of me, but I think you are reading the problem incorrectly - 2 identical fermions can't be in the same state, let alone 3. You probably mean 3 different fermions in the $S_z = +\frac{1}{2}$ state. Like an up, down and strange quark, or something to that effect.

Comment: Sorry, where did I say two or more of these fermions were in the same state?  I am well aware of the Pauli exclusion principle, and, looking over my question, I can't see where I wrote anything to suggest that.

Thank you for responding, whatever the case.

Comment: In Greiner and Muller, I'm referring to problem 9.1 on p. 300.  This problem gives you the basis functions of the permutation group $S_3$ in terms of single-particle wavefunctions $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$.

Comment: I just wasn't sure what you meant by 'identical particles' except for same state?

Comment: By identical, I meant indistinguishable, I guess.  Sorry for the confusion, but identical is the terminology used in every reference I've found on the problem so far.

Comment: Related: [Adding 3 electron spins](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29443).

Answer (score 2):

The L=1 rep is a 3 dimensional irep of $SU(2)$; the S=1/2 rep is a 2 dimensional irep.
Combining angular momentum (L=1) and spin (S=1/2) gives the tensor product
rep $3 \otimes 2$ which is 6 dimensional. You are looking for the third
exterior product of this : $A^3(3 \otimes 2)$ which is 20 dimensional and
decomposes into $6 \oplus 4 \oplus 4 \oplus 4 \oplus 2$ irreps. These
correspond to j=5/2,3/2,3/2,3/2,1/2 .

Comment: Thank you, Y Macdisi.  I should be more specific, reading your response:  Would the $j=5/2$ have to be $L_{tot}=2$, $S_{tot}=1/2$?  If so, I can't see how one gets just 6 states, from the work done in Greiner and Muller's book.  Would the $j=3/2$ be $L_{tot}=1$, $S_{tot}=1/2$ (for 10 of the 12), or $L_{tot}=0$, $S_{tot}=3/2$ (for 2 of the 12)?  If so, I can't see how to get exactly 10 states from my $L_{tot}=1$ wavefunctions, in terms of single particle momentum states $|\pm1\rangle$ or $|0\rangle$.  There just seem to be too many possible choices of single-particle angular momentum states.

Comment: By the way, from Greiner and Muller's book, it seems there are two mixed symmetric and two mixed antisymmetric wave functions, expressed in terms of single particle wavefunctions $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$, where each of $\alpha$, $\beta$, and $\gamma$ can take on the values $|+1\rangle$, $|0\rangle$, or $|-1\rangle$.  For instance, the two orthonormal wavefunctions which are symmetric under exchange of $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are the following:

$1/2 \psi_1 = 1/2\left[\alpha\beta\gamma + \beta\alpha\gamma-\gamma\beta\alpha-\gamma\alpha\beta\right]$

Comment: and 


$1/\sqrt{3}\psi_2' = 1/\sqrt{3}\left[1/2\left(\alpha\beta\gamma+\beta\alpha\gamma+\gamma\beta\alpha+ \gamma \alpha\beta\right)-\alpha\gamma\beta-\beta\gamma\alpha\right]$

Comment: There are also two more orthonormal wave functions, which are mixed antisymmetric under exchange of $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

These four mixed (anti)symmetric wave functions must have either $L_{tot}=2$ or $L_{tot}=1$, it seems.  They must be multiplied by the appropriate mixed (anti)symmetric spin wave functions to eventually form fully antisymmetric total wave functions corresponding to all of the $j=5/2$ states, and most of the $j=3/2$ states.

Comment: Another way to think of it, is that, for three spin $1/2$ particles, the two mixed symmetric spin wave functions are the following:

$|1/2,-1/2\rangle = -1/\sqrt{6}\left(2\Downarrow\Downarrow\Uparrow-\Uparrow\Downarrow\Downarrow-\Downarrow \Uparrow\Downarrow \right)$

$|1/2,1/2\rangle = 1/\sqrt{6}\left(2\Uparrow\Uparrow\Downarrow-\Uparrow\Downarrow\Uparrow-\Downarrow \Uparrow\Uparrow \right)$

Comment: The two mixed antisymmetric spin wave functions are the following:
$|1/2,-1/2\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2}\left(\Uparrow \Downarrow \Downarrow - \Downarrow \Uparrow \Downarrow \right)$

$|1/2,1/2\rangle = 1/\sqrt{2} \left(\Uparrow \Downarrow \Uparrow - \Downarrow \Uparrow \Uparrow \right)$

Comment: In place of $\Uparrow$ and $\Downarrow$, you could just put $|\pm1\rangle$ or $|0\rangle$, discounting all possibilities which are simply permutations of other possibilities.  This still seems to give too many possible orbital angular momentum states, which give more than 20 distinct total wavefunctions.

Comment: I do not have these books so I can't comment on how they construct the basis for these ireps. In the past I saw many "add hoc" ways of combining symmetric and antisymmetric parts ...(for example in the construction of the proton spin 1/2 wavefunction from quarks with spin). What they have is probably ok, but choosing a basis always has more degrees of freedom than knowing how the space decomposes under the group.

Comment: I don't think you can think of the j=5/2 state as being with L_{tot}=2, S_{tot}=1/2. An SU(2) irep is completely determined by a single label (here it's j). L and S are not necessarily conserved...

Comment: Thank you for responding again.  Naively, I would expect that $j=L_{tot}+S_{tot}$, and, given that $L=1$ and $L=2$ correspond to Young tableaux with mixed symmetry, the corresponding orbital angular momentum states would need to be paired with spin states of mixed symmetry, which only have $S_{tot}=1/2$.  Then it would seem to me that the only way to get $j=5/2$ would be from $L_{tot}=2$, $S_{tot}=1/2$.  Is this not the case?

Comment: It would be helpful if I knew the case where $\alpha=1$, $\beta=0$, and $\gamma=0$ was related to the case where $\alpha=-1$, $\beta=0$, and $\gamma=0$, such that I could throw the second one out.

Comment: It's too confusing to try to see how the L and S parts fit within the individual J ireps (to me at least). Same goes for trying to build things up with symmetrized and anti-symmetrized parts. Both these approaches do not scale to more complicated problems...

Comment: There are some other ways to get the Clebsch-Gordan coefficients that don't involve starting from Young tableaux as I did here, but they seem even more confusing.  The Wigner 6j symbols, I believe, are supposed to be exactly what I'm looking for, but they seem much more confusing than using Young tableaux.

Well, it is somewhat reassuring that you aren't telling me that the individual j ireps should correspond to particular L and S.

Anyway, thank you very much for your thoughts.