# Spin quantum states and spin observables of photons (spin 1 particles with 0 rest mass)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, quantum-spin, polarization, helicity

I was reading [Goldbring's article on the implications of $\text{MIP}^\ast=\text{RE}$](https://doi.org/10.1090/bull/1768) which contains a crash course-like overview of (classical, non-relativistic, non-QFT) quantum mechanics. This made me consider some questions. My question is ultimately concerned with a photon, i.e. a massless spin-$1$-particle, but I will start with what I understood about electrons, i.e. a massiv spin-$\frac12$-particle, and maybe there are already some mistakes or misconceptions there, of which I would be very happy if someone would point them out to me. My background: mathematician with some interest in computer science and physics, but not a professional.

**Spin of electrons**

Most of this is based on [a wikipedia article about spin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_(physics)) and I also found [this PSE question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/104591/) and [that one](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/29443/) helpful, although the last two are about spin-$\frac32$.

For $n=1$ electron the spin state space is $\mathcal{H}_1=\mathbb{C}^2=\text{span}(e_1,e_2)$ or more precisely the unit sphere in $\mathcal{H}_1$ is the set of all pure states. Here $e_i$ are standard basis vectors of tuple vector spaces.
The three Pauli matrices
$$
\sigma_x=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\1&0\end{pmatrix},
\sigma_y=\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\-i&0\end{pmatrix},
\sigma_z=\begin{pmatrix}1&0\\0&-1\end{pmatrix}
$$
are observables and any observable is a (real) linear combination of these three: $\sigma_u=u_x\sigma_x+u_y\sigma_y+u_z\sigma_z$ is up to normalization the spin measurement in direction $u=(u_x,u_y,u_z)^\top$. Up to multiplication by $i$, the imaginary unit, the 3-dimensional $\mathbb{R}$-vector space of observables is the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{su}(2)$ and thus the observables can be endowed with an algebra structure, i.e. a multiplication, which is useful to define the commutator of two observables.
Any (pure) state can be realized as an eigenstate of some observable, e.g. for $\sigma_z$ these are $\lvert1\rangle_z=\lvert\uparrow\rangle_z=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}=e_1$ and $\lvert-1\rangle_z=\lvert\downarrow\rangle_z=\begin{pmatrix}0\\1\end{pmatrix}=e_2$ usually denoted as spin up/down in $z$-direction. However, one could equally well take $\widetilde{\lvert1\rangle}_z=\begin{pmatrix}-1\\0\end{pmatrix}=-e_1$ and $\widetilde{\lvert-1\rangle}_z=\begin{pmatrix}0\\\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(-1+i)\end{pmatrix}=e^{3/4\pi i}e_2$ as scaling by a unit norm complex scalar only changes the phase, which is not observable in this situation. Also in the spin-$\frac12$-case one might take the scaled Pauli matrix $\frac12\sigma_z$ (or $\frac\hbar2\sigma_z$) to get half-integral eigenvectors and rather write $\lvert\frac12\rangle_z$ and $\lvert-\frac12\rangle_z$ etc.

For $n=2$ electrons the (pure) spin state space is $\mathcal{H}_2=\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_1=\mathbb{C}^2\otimes\mathbb{C}^2\cong\mathbb{C}^4=\text{span}(e_i)_{i=1}^4$ where a possible isomorphism could take the form $e_i\otimes e_j\mapsto e_{2(i-1)+j}$. Since $(e_i)_{i=1}^2$ were seen to be eigenstates for the $z$-direction spin measurement this expresses a basis of $\mathcal{H}_2$ as a tensor product of componentwise eigenstates. However this is not a good description with respect to the observables it turns out. There is a decomposition into singlet and triplet states (for clarity we start with a cumbersome notation and introduce convenient abbriviations):
$$
\mathcal{H}_2=\mathcal{H}_1\otimes\mathcal{H}_1=
\text{span}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\lvert\uparrow\rangle_z\otimes\lvert\downarrow\rangle_z-\lvert\downarrow\rangle_z\otimes\lvert\uparrow\rangle_z\right)\right)
\oplus
\text{span}\left(\lvert\uparrow\rangle_z\otimes\lvert\uparrow\rangle_z,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\lvert\uparrow\rangle_z\otimes\lvert\downarrow\rangle_z+\lvert\downarrow\rangle_z\otimes\lvert\uparrow\rangle_z\right),\lvert\downarrow\rangle_z\otimes\lvert\downarrow\rangle_z\right)=
\text{span}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\lvert\uparrow\downarrow\rangle-\lvert\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\right)\right)
\oplus
\text{span}\left(\lvert\uparrow\uparrow\rangle,\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\lvert\uparrow\downarrow\rangle+\lvert\downarrow\uparrow\rangle\right),\lvert\downarrow\downarrow\rangle\right)=
\text{span}\left(\lvert0,0\rangle\right)
\oplus
\text{span}\left(\lvert1,1\rangle,\lvert1,0\rangle,\lvert1,-1\rangle\right).
$$
In the last notation $\lvert s,m\rangle$ stands for the combined eigenstate for the two observables $S^2=S_x^2+S_y^2+S_z^2$ with eigenvalue $s(s+1)$ and $S_z$ with eigenvalue $m$. Here the $S_u$ are the directed spin observables on the tensor products induced from the Pauli matrices $\sigma_u$.
We focused on $\sigma_z$ but we could have instead employed any $\sigma_u$ for any direction $u$ and got the same up to isomorphism. Also note that we got basis elements that are not *pure tensors* (mathematically) but are still *pure states* (quantum mechanically).
Coming to the observables: Clearly $S_z=\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_z$ (Kronecker product) gives one and there are 8 further such observables (e.g. $\sigma_z\otimes\sigma_x$) spanning a 9-dimensional space of observables. On the other hand one can perform a measurement on one of the tensor factors without interfering with the other component: $\text{id}\otimes\sigma_u$ or $\sigma_u\otimes\text{id}$. This gives 6 more dimensions, however these measurements produce mixed states and not pure states. While it is clear to me, how one adds observables in the 9 dimensional space of Kronecker products of component observables, and within the two 3-dimensional spaces with one component the identity, the status of expressions like $\text{id}\otimes\sigma_x+\sigma_x\otimes\text{id}$ or $\text{id}\otimes\sigma_x+\sigma_y\otimes\sigma_z$ is not clear to me. In particular $\text{id}\otimes\sigma_x+\sigma_x\otimes\sigma_x=\left(\text{id}+\sigma_x\right)\otimes\sigma_x$ would suggest that $\text{id}+\sigma_x$ should be an observable for $n=1$ particle case and I am not sure about the status of this.
I assume that again any pure state can be realized as an eigenstate of some observable, although I am not sure how that observable would look like for a pure state like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lvert0,0\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lvert1,-1\rangle$ which "mixes" singlet and triplet states.

**Spin of a photon**

Now lets consider a photon, a massless spin-$1$-"particle". Since the photon has no inner structure I would have assumed that singlet subspace is no longer relevant and the spin is governed by a triplet space $\cong\mathbb{C}^3$. However [wikipedia on photons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon#Spin_angular_momentum) tells me that the state space is actually generated by the two circular polarizations (L,R) as a possible basis. However just in the next section they speak about three eigenvalues $-1,0,1$ and explain in a footnote that the 0-eigenstate corresponds to a linear combination of L and R (resp. $-1$- and $1$-states) - this does not make sense to me.

**Question(s):** How does one explicitly describe the space of (pure) states for the spin of a photon? Can this be done in isolation or does one always have to also consider the momentum and/or angular momentum of the photon? What are the (spin-)observables for the photon, how would one describe the set of all observables explicitly? Are there mixed states for (the spin of) a single photon and which observables produce them, if so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came across [this answer to a similar question by ACuriousMind](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/265646/348563) which gives a detailed background for an answer to my questions. I extract short answers to my questions, the detailed explanations to them can be found in the link. It seems that for a proper explanation you have to go to relativistic quantum mechanics, classical quantum mechanics will not do.

- Massless particles do not have spin, but they have something analogous, namely helicity. The difference lies in the different algebra representations for massive and massless particles in relativistic QM.
- Helicity is aligned with (linear) momentum. In contrast spin for massive particles can be measured in any direction $u$ via the spin operator $S_u$. To ensure [gauge invariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spin_angular_momentum_of_light#Mathematical_expression) only the spin operator in direction of the momentum is applicable and it measures helicity. There is another degree of freedom which is [orbital angular momentum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orbital_angular_momentum_of_light), which seems to be essentially independent of helicity (resp. spin angular momentum as it is also called).
- The two eigenvalues for the helicity of a "spin 1 photon" are $\pm 1$ (resp. $\pm \hbar$) associated to the spin operator aligned with momentum as observable. The eigenvalues are also sometimes referred to as L (corresponding to $1$, i.e. helicity points in direction of momentum) and R (corresponding to $-1$, i.e. helicity points in opposite direction of momentum). L/R stand for left/right polarization.
- There is no $0$ eigenstate, however superposition of pure L and pure R (to equal parts) gives you linear polarized photons. Measuring helicity of a linear polarized photon will give you either $1$ or $-1$, but $0$ on average for repeated measurement with several linear polarized photons.