# Spin of 3 particles

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, hilbert-space, group-representations

I am trying to decompose the isospins of a three particle state using Clebsch-Gordan coefficients such as:

$|1,1\rangle \otimes |1/2,-1/2\rangle \otimes |1,0\rangle$

Decomposing the first two states gives:

$|1,1\rangle \otimes |1/2,-1/2\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|3/2,1/2\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|1/2,1/2\rangle$

And then these combined with the third state give:

$|3/2,1/2\rangle \otimes |1,0 \rangle = \sqrt{\frac{3}{5}}|5/2,1/2\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{1}{15}}|3/2,1/2\rangle - \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|1/2,1/2\rangle$

$|1/2,1/2\rangle \otimes |1,0 \rangle = \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}|3/2,1/2\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{1}{3}}|1/2,1/2\rangle$

When I combine these all together I get:

$|1,1\rangle \otimes |1/2,-1/2\rangle \otimes |1,0\rangle = \sqrt{\frac{1}{5}} |5/2,1/2\rangle + \frac{10+\sqrt{5}}{15} |3/2,1/2\rangle + \frac{-1+\sqrt{2}}{3}|1/2,1/2\rangle$

Which has to be incorrect as this state is not normalised. Basically my question is, what am I doing wrong?

Edit: What I'm attempting to calculate is amplitudes for processes like $\Lambda p \to \Lambda p \pi^0$ using isospin states for all of the particles.

Comment: One assumes you are using [Racah's W-coeffs?](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Racah_W-coefficient).

Comment: I've been using Wolfram Alpha's CG coefficient calculator https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Clebsch-Gordan+calculator

Comment: You are right that you should get a normalized answer if you did it right, with the proper (sparse!) 18x18 orthogonal matrix which changes basis! (See, e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285902/clebsch-gordan-with-three-particles/285953#285953)  for the addition of 3 spin 1/2s.) In your case, using dimensionalities, i.e. 2j+1 s, $3\otimes 3 \otimes 2= 6\oplus 4 \oplus 4 \oplus 2\oplus 2$, so there are two different spin 3/2s and two 1/2s ... And you have to 6-j distribute them suitably... That's what's wrong.

Comment: The issue here is that there are two copies of $s=3/2$ and $s=1/2$ that occur in the decomposition of $1\otimes 1/2 \otimes 1$ and you need to separate states in distinct copies of $s=3/2$ and $s=1/2$.  As mentioned by @CosmasZachos this involves Racah technology.

Comment: re: your latest edit... Isn't Λ an isosinglet? what's the fuss?

Comment: Bad example sorry, that's one of the ones I got correct, Lambda is indeed an isosinglet. The one's I'm having trouble with are like $\Lambda p \to \Sigma^+ n \pi^0$

Comment: I recall the PDG (fat book, not booklet) has an entire section of SU(3) isoscalar factors, Clebsches, couplings, etc.... is it clear SU(3) doesn't get you more. The latest one you wrote is an octet going to three such....

Comment: Is there anything wrong with trying $3\otimes 3 \otimes 2 = (5 \oplus 3 \oplus 1) \otimes 2 = 5\otimes 2 \oplus 3 \otimes 2 \oplus 1 \otimes 2$ and saying that the $3\otimes 2$ representation are the $\Sigma N$ states, the $1\otimes 2$ are the $\Lambda N$ states ?

Comment: How do I use Racah coefficients in the context of this problem specifically? This is the first time I've ever heard of them and I can't find an example of their use anywhere.

Comment: [Messiah v II](https://archive.org/details/QuantumMechanicsVolumeIi) Ch XIII §29 and Appendix C , § II . Software programs incorporate them, as in the presumably sound answer...  I think the mother of the [PDG review](https://ccwww.kek.jp/pdg/2018/reviews/rpp2018-rev-su3-isoscalar-factors.pdf) should be helpful, if/when found.

Answer (score 1):

Using software, I get:

> for ket in Ket(1,1)*Ket(0.5,-0.5)*Ket(1,0):
>       ...:     print unicode(ket)
>       ...:
>       ...:
>
> √（2∕9) |½, ½⟩
>
> -⅓|½, ½⟩
>
> ⅔|1½, ½⟩
>
> 1∕25 |1½, ½⟩
>
> √（⅕) |2½, ½⟩

whose coefficients add (in quadrature) to unity. So the question is, why can't you add the two $|\frac 1 2, \frac 1 2\rangle$ kets coherently (and likewise for the two $|\frac 3 2, \frac 1 2\rangle$ kets)?

See the comments--there are different mixed symmetry representations in the final answer with the same multiplicity.

Answer (score 0):

So the key point here is to realize that the coupling 
$$
1\otimes \frac{1}{2}\otimes 1
$$
will contain some final $J$ values more than once.  Indeed 
$$
1\otimes \frac{1}{2}=\frac{3}{2}\oplus \frac{1}{2} \tag{1}
$$ 
and coupling this to $1$ will 
produce, for instance,  two types of states with final $J=\frac{1}{2}$, depending on the intermediate $J_{12}$ value.  Thus, copy will come from the $J_{12}=\frac{3}{2}$ and the other will come from the $J_{12}=1$ states of (1).

To be systematic write
$$
\vert 1,1\rangle
\vert\textstyle\frac{1}{2},-\frac{1}{2}\rangle
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}\vert \frac{3}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle + \sqrt{\frac{2}{3}}
\vert\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2}\rangle\, .\tag{2}
$$
Coupling the $\frac{3}{2}$ state to $1$, the part proportional to final $J=\frac{1}{2}$ using the CG $C_{3/2,1/2;1,0}^{1/2,1/2}=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}$ yields
$\vert \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2};J_{12}=\frac{3}{2}\rangle$ with
$$
\langle \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2};J_{12}=\frac{3}{2}\vert
1,1;\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} ; 1,0\rangle
=-\frac{1}{3}
$$
but going through the $J_{12}=\frac{1}{2}$ produces a *different* $J=\frac{1}{2}$ state with
$$
\langle \textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2};J_{12}=\frac{1}{2}\vert 
1,1; \frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{2} ; 1,0\rangle
=+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3}
$$
You can actually check that $\vert\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2};J_{12}=\frac{1}{2}\rangle$ is really different from 
$\vert\textstyle\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{2};J_{12}=\frac{3}{2}\rangle$ by computing
their explicitly expressions in terms of $j_1=1,j_2=\frac{1}{2}, j_3=1$ states; you will see that these are *distinct* linear combinations of the $j_1=1,j_2=\frac{1}{2}, j_3=1$ states.