# Do Clebsch Gordan Coefficients add to one when squared for adding 3 isospin states?

Tags: particle-physics, pions, isospin-symmetry

I've been calculating the possible isospin states for $\pi^0\pi^+\pi^-$ state and get this as my final answer after referencing the Clebsch Gordan Coefficients table:

$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}|30\rangle+\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|20\rangle+\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{15}}|10\rangle-\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|00\rangle$$

However, if I square the magnitudes in front of the kets and sum them, I don't get one, and this is because of the factor of $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{15}}$ which comes from the fact that I added the $\pi^+\pi^-$ first, which gave a $|20\rangle$, $|10\rangle$, and $|00\rangle$ state. Adding the $\pi^0$ to this gives a state of $|10\rangle$ from both adding $|2 0\rangle|10\rangle$ and $|00\rangle|10\rangle$, which gives me that factor of $\frac{\sqrt{5}-1}{\sqrt{15}}$ in total. Is there any reason why the sum of the squares doesn't add to one? Or is my calculation wrong? Here's all of my work if it helps:

[image]

Comment: Hint: perhaps there are more than one independent isovectors $|01\rangle$? See, e.g., [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/340625/3-particles-spin-using-clebsch-gordan-coefficients).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to suspect your conceptual error when you *assume* the two isotriplet pieces you found in your stepwise composition are identical, when, in fact, they are independent, and orthogonal! The correct answer, is instead,
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{10}}|30\rangle +\frac{1}{\sqrt{3}}|20\rangle +\frac{\sqrt{5}} {\sqrt{15}}|10\rangle -\frac{ 1} {\sqrt{15}}|10\rangle ' -\frac{1}{\sqrt{6}}|00\rangle ,$$
where the isovector states $|10\rangle$ and $|10\rangle'$ are orthogonal to each other and the other states, isoscalar and isotensors. *Now* your answer is normalized to one, as you may check.

The generalists will send you off to learn about [Racah coefficients](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/6-j_symbol), but, in your case, the two states are evident by inspection, displaying the $I_3$ components of the respective wave functions you found, with *very different symmetries*, ensuring their mutual orthogonality,
$$
|10\rangle = (\uparrow \downarrow 0   +  \downarrow \uparrow 0   - 0\uparrow \downarrow    - 0 \downarrow \uparrow  )/2\\
|10\rangle '= (\uparrow \downarrow 0   -  \downarrow \uparrow 0   + 0\uparrow \downarrow    - 0 \downarrow \uparrow  )/2 ~.  
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I hadn't considered that they'd actually be orthogonal states!