# Symmetries of Wigner $3j$-symbols by exchange

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, symmetry, group-theory

I know that Wigner $3j$-symbols have certain symmetry factors arising by exchange of two columns within one symbol.

But what happens if you have two 3j symbols and do an exchange like this:

$ \left(\,\begin{matrix}%
     j_1&j_2&J\\%
     m_1&m_2&-M_J %6      
   \end{matrix}\,\right)% 
\left(\,\begin{matrix}%
     J&j_3&j\\%
     M_J&m_3&-m_j %6      
   \end{matrix}\,\right)%
\Rightarrow 
\left(\,\begin{matrix}%
     j_3&j_2&J\\%
     m_3&m_2&-M_J %6      
   \end{matrix}\,\right)% 
\left(\,\begin{matrix}%
     J&j_1&j\\%
     M_J&m_1&-m_j %6      
   \end{matrix}\,\right)%$

So I did an exchange of $j_1$ with $j_3$ and since that operation is an exchange between two 3j symbols, does there also arise a symmetry factor 
$(-1)^{something}$ ?

That is an example of three body coupling, where the first two states of the bra $j_1$ and $j_2$ are coupled to $J$ and then $J$ and the third state $j_3$ are coupled to $j$.

Comment: Somewhat related: [Adding 3 electron spins](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/29443/adding-3-electron-spins). The behaviour of multiple additions of angular momenta under particle exchange need not be particularly pretty.

Comment: @EmilioPisanty Thanks, but here I am not dealing with electrons. It's about Nuclei and there is not written how the symmetry behaviour is under exchange of the coupling order

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, states with total angular momentum $J$ obtained from the triple couplings $j_1j_2j_3$ can be obtained in a number of ways.

A first is to couple $j_1j_2$ to $j_{12}$, and couple this to $j_3$ to get $j$, giving states symbolically denoted by $\vert (j_1j_2)j_{12}j_3;jM\rangle$.  A second is to couple first $j_2j_3$ to $j_{23}$, and then $j_1$ to this to get $j$, with states denoted $\vert j_1(j_2j_3)j_{23};jM\rangle$.

The states $\vert j_1(j_2j_3)j_{23};JM\rangle$ are not linearly independent from the $\vert (j_1j_2)j_{12}j_3;JM\rangle$.  In fact, the overlap is related to a $6j$ coefficient:
$$
\langle  (j_1j_2)j_{12}j_3;jM\vert  j_1(j_2j_3)j_{23};jM\rangle
=(-1)^{j_1+j_2+j_3+J} \sqrt{(2j_{12}+1)(2j_{23}+1)}
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
j_1&j_2&j_{12}\\
j_3&j&j_{23}\end{array}\right\}\, .
$$
and the overlap need not be $\pm 1$.

Your specific case seem to have $j_{12}=j_{23}=J$.  I think you should follow that route to understand the effects of your permutation $j_1\leftrightarrow j_3$, i.e. write states in $\vert (j_1j_2)Jj_3;jm\rangle$ basis, with CG and all,  permute $j_1$ and $j_3$, and then take the overlap of the resulting state $P_{13}\vert (j_1j_2)Jj_3;jm\rangle$ with your original basis $\vert (j_1j_2)Jj_3;jm\rangle$ to get the effect of the permutation.  There are equalities of the type
$$
\sum_{e\epsilon} (-1)^{2e}\sqrt{(2c+1)(2d+1)} C_{b\beta;d\delta}^{e\epsilon}C^{e\epsilon}_{f\varphi;c\gamma}
\left\{\begin{array}{ccc}
a&b&c\\
e&f&d\end{array}\right\}= C_{a\alpha;b\beta}^{c\gamma}C_{a\alpha;f\varphi}^{d\delta}
$$
which can be found in

> Varshalovich, D.A., Moskalev, A.N. and Khersonskii, V.K.M., 1988. Quantum theory of angular momentum.

to help you sort this out.   The most explicit example of this procedure I could find is in [this paper](https://aip.scitation.org/doi/pdf/10.1063/1.532911):

> Rowe, D.J., Sanders, B.C. and De Guise, H., 1999. Representations of the Weyl group and Wigner functions for SU (3). Journal of Mathematical Physics, 40(7), pp.3604-3615.

where the effect of permutations is examined, although in a slightly different context.

Comment: Thank you, that helped me a lot!